# Lambda not in function doesn't work for more than one word in Python

Tags: pandas, lambda, contains

I would like to filter dataframe by lambda if condition

I have a "product name" and "category1" columns and "if product name" not contains ("boxer","boxers","sock","socks") words I would like to change "category1" column as "Other", but below code change all of them as "other" example even contains "sock"

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'product_name': ["blue shirt", " medium boxers", "red jackets ", "blue sock"],})


df["category1"]=df.apply(lambda x: "Other" if ("boxer","boxers","sock","socks" not in x["product_name"] ) else x["category1"], axis=1)
```

I expected below results

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'product_name': ["blue shirt", " medium boxers", "red jackets ", "blue sock"],
 'category1'["other", Nan, "other ", "Nan"],})
```

Thank you for your support

Comment: You column probably never contain the `("boxer","boxers","sock","socks")` tuple ;) Please fix your formatting and provide an unambiguous example input as text

Comment: sorry my mistake I revised question, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `str.contains`:

```
items = ("boxer","boxers","sock","socks")

import numpy as np
df["category1"] = np.where(df['product_name'].str.contains('|'.join(items)),
                           np.nan,  # value is True
                           'Other') # value if False
```

output:

```
     product_name category1
0      blue shirt     Other
1   medium boxers       nan
2    red jackets      Other
3       blue sock       nan
```

Comment: That works too, thank you